# Rabbit Mq fails to start

Tags: centos, rabbitmq

Just installed RabitMq on a brand new CentOs6.6 server ( rabbitMq 3.4.1, erlang says 17 ), and it fails to start.

```
Starting rabbitmq-server: FAILED - check /var/log/rabbitmq/startup_{log, _err}
rabbitmq-server.
```

startup log

```
Stack trace:
[{inet_gethost_native,ensure_started,0,
                     [{file,"inet_gethost_native.erl"},{line,548}]},
{inet_gethost_native,getit,2,
                     [{file,"inet_gethost_native.erl"},{line,487}]},
{inet,gethostbyname_tm_native,4,[{file,"inet.erl"},{line,1094}]},
{inet,gethostbyname,3,[{file,"inet.erl"},{line,459}]},
{erl_epmd,port_please1,3,[{file,"erl_epmd.erl"},{line,81}]},
{rabbit_networking,record_distribution_listener,0,[]},
{rabbit_networking,boot,0,[]},
{rabbit,'-run_step/3-lc$^1/1-1-',2,[]}]

BOOT FAILED
===========

Error description:
{could_not_start,rabbit,
   {bad_return,
       {{rabbit,start,[normal,[]]},
        {'EXIT',
            {rabbit,failure_during_boot,
                {boot_step,networking,
                    {could_not_start_server,inet_gethost_native}}}}}}}
```

Let me know if you need any other info.  Any help would be appreciated, I think this sever is cursed.  Last time i get a new server around Halloween.

It looks like it running `status`.  I have a line for my host, there is one with the ip address to, but removing that didn't help, in etc/hosts.

```
Status of node rabbit@host4 ...
Error: unable to connect to node rabbit@host4: nodedown

DIAGNOSTICS
===========

attempted to contact: [rabbit@host4]

rabbit@host4:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on host4
  * epmd reports: node 'rabbit' not running at all
                  no other nodes on host4
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmqctl-29678@host4'
- home dir: /var/lib/rabbitmq
```

I have this process running too.  If it helps.

```
root@host4 [981 19:09:47 ~]# ps aux|grep rabbit
rabbitmq 16068  0.0  0.0  10828   528 ?        S    16:13   0:00 /usr/lib64/erlang/erts-6.2/bin/epmd -daemon
```

also
    running hostname -f shows me the correct hostname.  For example

```
  host4.mysite.com
```

IN reply I ran those commands: rabbit was not running and would not connect as the app_start.

Here is the results of `rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME}\n' |grep erlang`

```
erlang-mnesia
erlang-otp_mibs
erlang-reltool
erlang-snmp
erlang-erl_docgen
erlang-examples
erlang-erts
erlang-cosEvent
erlang-ic
erlang-debugger
erlang-stdlib
erlang-cosProperty
erlang-jinterface
erlang-typer
erlang-compiler
erlang-asn1
erlang-cosNotification
erlang-cosFileTransfer
erlang-parsetools
erlang-wx
erlang-dialyzer
erlang
erlang-solutions
erlang-hipe
erlang-ssl
erlang-ssh
erlang-percept
erlang-odbc
erlang-webtool
erlang-megaco
erlang-syntax_tools
erlang-public_key
erlang-edoc
erlang-cosTransactions
erlang-erl_interface
erlang-observer
erlang-common_test
erlang-kernel
erlang-runtime_tools
erlang-orber
erlang-eldap
erlang-sasl
erlang-os_mon
erlang-inets
erlang-diameter
erlang-tools
erlang-crypto
erlang-cosTime
erlang-eunit
erlang-test_server
erlang-gs
erlang-ose
erlang-xmerl
erlang-cosEventDomain
erlang-et
```

I do have ip_tables, so I thought it might be a firewall issue but I can successfully telnet to the host name rabbit is using with `4369` as the port.

When I run `nmap -p 5672`

```
Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-11-03 20:30 CST
Nmap scan report for host4 (127.0.0.1)
Host is up (0.000049s latency).
Other addresses for host4 (not scanned): xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
rDNS record for 127.0.0.1: localhost.localdomain
PORT     STATE  SERVICE
5672/tcp closed amqp

Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.06 seconds
```

What's the best way to remove this thing, when I do `yum remove rabbitmq-server` and instal an older version say `3.3.5` I get this error message

```
Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
Failed to create aux thread
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Can you resolve hostnames?

Comment: Yes i can ping the hostname etc.

Comment: Show us what `hostname -f` displays.

Comment: P.S. It is always good idea to post RabbitMQ and erlang version you use.

Comment: @zaq178miami - updated

Comment: @ArtisiticPhoenix, try to run `hostname -f`. Does it run successfully?

Comment: @zaq178miami - yes it shows me the correct host.

Comment: Please do the following: /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl stop_app /etc/init.d/rabbitmq-server restart /usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl status If `rabbitmq-server` is not up, re-run it using `/usr/sbin/rabbitmqctl start_app`. Also, please run this: rpm -qa --queryformat '%{NAME}\n' |grep erlang Please paste the outputs of the `rpm` command and the `rabbitmqctl status` (after the 3 steps listed above). How did you install `erlang` and how did you install `rabbitmq-server`? source / rpm ? Edit #1: Please verify that the server's host name is written correctly in `/etc/hosts` on the line of `127.0.0.1`, also check `/e

Comment: This is true thanks for the help first off.  I'll post the results of the rpm grep deal.  The other commands just told me rabbit is not running and gave same error message.

Comment: Please check Edit #1 in my answer.

Comment: @ltai  -  not setup using ssl yet, basically a fresh install from rpms, we do have ip_tables on, but selinux appears to be disabled ( that's what sestatus says )

Comment: @ItaiGanot should have mentioned the status is identical to the one I originally put.

Comment: The reason why I'm so familiar with this subject is that I installed my first RabbitMQ server about two days ago, I'd like to refer you to my question, read my answer there and if you go through the steps there I'm sure it will work, as I used the same set of commands to install 4 more machine like that,
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26697628/rabbitmq-unable-to-enable-rabbitmq-priority-queue-plugin-particularly-but-why/26697726?noredirect=1#comment41989984_26697726

Comment: I would try to disable iptables just for the test

Comment: I tried that through WHM last night actually, had no effect.  I've installed rabbit a few times :) but I'm on a loss on this one.  Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference I have solved the issue, with some help from the RabbitMq community which pointed me in this direction, by a simple statement.

> This suggests Erlang VM cannot create a thread. Do you have any resource or security restrictions in place?

This was directly in response to 2 items.

```
 Failed to create aux thread
```

Not sure why it didn't occur to me before, because I did see this in the erlang dump

```
 processes: 13064032
 processes_used: 13064032
```

However I am not sure how the number of erlang processes convert to system process, but regardless I thought it was a bug or programming incompatibility.  It just didn't make a whole lot of sense because the installation went smoothly on my virtual development server.  As well as our old CentOs 5.1 server.  Also as this was a new, sever with > 3x the speed of our old one, I thought hitting resources limits was not an issue.  I just needed someone to say it to make it `click` in my mind.

Anyway, after some researching I ran this command

```
#su rabbitmq
bash-4.1$ ulimit -a
=============================
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 128218
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 131072
open files                      (-n) 4096
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 100
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

The important thing here is this part:

```
 max user processes              (-u) 100
```

Checking my development box ( which has a functional RabbitMq installation with the management plugin ) I further saw this.

```
 Erlang processes   206
```

So it doesn't really take a genius to figure out that `206` is more then `100`  so after some more research I discovered the default value for this setting is typically 1024, and that i can change it in `/etc/security/limits.conf`  In that file I found

```
 *               hard    nproc           100
```

So I just upped that to the `1024` amount for the rabbitmq user

```
 rabbitmq                 hard    nproc           1024
```

And it fired right up!  After starting it and checking the status, I see this

```
 {processes,[{limit,1048576},{used,147}]},
```

I believe the limit here is system wide? Still not really sure how the erlang process and these other process numbers relate.

So in conclusion 100 process is not enough for erlang to work.  This is a cloud hosted SSAE 16 dedicated webserver, typically the hosting company sets these up for use for `resellers`, ie. you can farm out parts of the server to host you're clients websites. This is most likely why they set a default limit so low.  We use this type of server because we do a lot of database querying and report writing, and it offers a fair amount of power for what we pay.  So while the hardware meets our needs, the configuration doesn't fit our use case as well.

Hopefully this can help someone in the future.